# How to know which core that send the inter-processor interrupt?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am working on ARM64. I add an inter-processor interrupt (IPI) handler in `void handle_IPI(int ipinr, struct pt_regs *regs)` in `linux/arch/arm64/kernel/smp.c`.

When I get an IPI, I want to know which core sends this IPI. For example, core 3 sends an IPI to core 0, then core 0 gets the IPI, I want to know that this IPI is from core 3 in the IPI handler.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm recently working on IPI on cortex-A9 platform, which is using ARM GIC as the interrupt controller. After some code reading, I found the core information is lost in [irq-gic.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c#L388). Maybe you should modify the handle_IPI prototype or call your specific IPI handler before handle_IPI. Both are the ugly way of adding customized IPI handler with trigger information.